# Is it pointless to have both "class" and "new()" constraints in a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I am wondering if it makes any sense to have both "class" and "new()" constraints when defining a generic class. As in the following example:

```
class MyParanoidClass<T> where T : class, new()
{
 //content
}
```

Both constraints specify that T should be a reference type. While the "class" constraint does not imply that a implicit constructor exists, the "new()" constraint does require a "class" with an additional public constructor definition.

My final (formulation for the) question is: do I have any benefits from defining a generic class as in the above statement, or does "new()" encapsulate both constraints?

Comment: I don't think `new()` forces a reference type, just a public parameterless constructor, which value types can have (but I think they all have this anyway for being value types so it's next to pointless).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Value types *always* have a public parameterless constructor. And it is not pointless, because the `new()` constraint allows the code inside the class to create a new instance of `T` via `new T()`. This is not possible if the constraint is omitted.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yes I carry on to say that, but fair enough on the pointless bit. However, that'll likely be the same as `default(T)`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: No, certainly not. `default(T)` is `null` for a reference type. This is very different from `new T()` which is a new instance.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I am referring to value types.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Sure. But consider the example in my answer. No matter whether T is a value type or a reference type, you can use `new T();` to create a new instance of `T`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yes I know. I was always talking in the context of value types, as a whole of course it isn't pointless.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Ah, ok. I wasn't aware of you only commenting in that context, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`new()` doesn't imply a reference type, so: No, `class` is not redundant when using `new()`.

The following code demonstrates that:

```
void Main()
{
    new MyParanoidClass<S>();
}

struct S {}

class MyParanoidClass<T> where T : new()
{
    //content
}
```

This code compiles, proving that `new()` doesn't care if you use a reference or a value type.

Comment: +1 Clearly stated [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth IMO even documentation isn't really clear. "struct" implies "new()" but/then "new()" cannot be used with "struct" (even if they don't say so).

Comment: @Adriano `new` can be used with `struct`, they have constructors.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: What Adriano means is that the `new()` constraint can't be used with the `struct` constraint, because the `struct` constraint does indeed imply the `new()` constraint, because all structs have a public parameterless constructor (and you can't do anything about it).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth no, you can't have "new()" constraint in conjunction with "struct" (I supposed because this time is really implied).

Comment: @Adriano You didn't actually say *constraint*, I thought you were referring to calling `new int()` for example.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth because they were the topic. I learned by examples (from documentation) to leave something implicit! LOL

Answer (score 1):

No they are not useless.

First parameter **class** ensures that the type argument must be a reference type, including any class, interface, delegate, or array type,

whereas second parameter **new()** ensures that it has a parameter less default constructor. It will not work for any class that doesn't have parameter less default constructor.